# Can a finite set support a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Assume the set $\Omega$ is finite (finite number of elements). $A$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$. It is clear that $A$ can be an algebra, but is $A$ then also automatically a $\sigma$-algebra? If not, can it actually ever be a $\sigma$-algebra due to the finite nature of $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: Yes, an algebra over a finite set is the same as a $\sigma$-algebra over the same set. The two definitions coincide, which you can clearly see if you just go through the axioms for a $\sigma$-algebra. You can see that an algebra over a finite sets satisfies all the axioms.

---

Second question: a finite set can have a $\sigma$-algebra attached to it. There is nothing in the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra that demands a set be infinite.

In fact, in reality, we often deal with finite $\sigma$-algebras. For example, if you are flipping a fair coin, you essencially have a universal set $U=\{\text{heads}, \text{tails}\}$ on which you define a $\sigma$-algebra $2^U$ (the powerset) and then define a measure as

$$\mu(\{\emptyset\})=0\\
\mu(\{\text{heads}\}) = \mu(\{\text{tails}\}) = \frac12\\
\mu(U) = 1$$